# density function of a random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

Let the density function of a random variable Y be given by
$f(y) = e^{-y}$ 
for $y ≥ 0$,
$0$ otherwise 
a. (3 pts) Find the cumulative distribution function F(y). 
b. (7 pts) Find P(Y ≤ 2|Y ≥ 1)
c. (10 pts) Find the moment generating function of Y and use it to ﬁnd E(Y ) and V (Y)

For a, I did the integral of $e^{-y}$ from 0 to y. I got $-e^{-y} + 1$
 for $y > 0$.

For B, can I solve this juts like other conditional probabilities? So $P(Y ≤ 2$ int $Y ≥ 1)/P(Y ≥ 1)$

If so, is the answer of the numerator of that quotient the integral from 1 to 2 of f(y)? Thanks. 
PS: For C, I'm totally clueless, I don't know why moment generating functions just don't make a lot of sense to me so far.

Comment: I think you're doing everything correctly

Comment: Just plug in the formula for the Moment generating function. **Definition:** Moment Generating function of a random variable $Y$ is $$\phi_Y(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tY}].$$